# Does $(D_{v}f)(x)>0$ implies $(D_{-v} f)(x)<0$?

Tags: vector-analysis

Is this correct?

Assume that $(D_{v}f)(x)>0$ for some point $x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and some vector $v\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Then,

\begin{align}
  (D_{-v}f)(x) &= \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x-hv)-f(x)}{h}\\
   &= - \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x-hv)-f(x)}{-h}\\
  &= -(D_{v}f)(x)<0
\end{align}
I know that maybe this question is trivial but I am not sure if I am understanding well.

Comment: This is correct, although I would include one more step, substituting $k$ for $-h$.

Comment: Thank you so much!